# Laravel React mix babel loader error

Tags: laravel, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to setup Laravel with React using [Laravel-mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix)

I couldn't use ES6 in my React components. For example:

```
functionName = () => {
    console.log('doesnt work');
}
```

It throws an error that says:

> BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token(6:10)

(6:10) is pointing my fat arrow function.
I have `webpack.mix.js` file in the root that comes along with Laravel-mix. I also added `.babelrc` file with the following code:

```
{
"presets": [
  [
    "es2015",
    {
      "modules": false
    }
  ],
  "react"
]}
```

I've made sure that I installed `babel-core`, `babel-loader`, `babel-preset-2015`, `babel-preset-stage-3`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I configure this with `webpack.config.js` as I couldn't find any such file in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

The class properties syntax that you're using is [not available in `babel-preset-es2015`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/), but can be installed separately. You'll find it under [`transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). To stay up to date though, you might be better off with [`babel-preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) instead.

Did you check if the ES6 shorthand method properties syntax works with your setup? How about

```
functionName() {
    console.log('does this work?');
}
```